# Can JavaScript draw dashed lines?

Tags: javascript

I am a JavaScript newbie. I know JavaScript can draw lines, but can it draw dashed lines? If it can, how can I do so? Can it draw anti-aliased lines? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: Dotted / Dashed lines in Raphael.js are set via the attr `stroke-dasharray` - [more on that, plus examples, here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940316/how-to-use-attrs-stroke-dasharray-stroke-linecap-stroke-linejoin-in-raphaeljs/13884772)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just drawing lines, why not use CSS border property:

```
border-top:1px dashed #000;
```

Comment: did you mean `1px dashed #000`?