# Adding buttons to a chart - svg

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, morris.js

I want to develop an interactive chart using a JS library. In this chart I want to have buttons (inside the chart), in this way (in red):

[image]

I want also to change the line type (dotted for example).

I tried Morris.js but this lib is not allowing me to do what I want to do.

Is there any other library that I can use instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's possible with `Morris.js`, but you need to add some code to Morris (latest version 0.5.1) to draw dotted lines:

Extend Morris and add a parameter called `lineStyle` and set this parameter to `.` in the Morris Area configuration.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13884772/1351076) for the possible values for raphael.js line style:

```
["", "-", ".", "-.", "-..", ". ", "- ", "--", "- .", "--.", "--.."]
```

On `mouseover` solution:

```js
(function () {
    var $, MyMorris;

    MyMorris = window.MyMorris = {};
    $ = jQuery;

    MyMorris = Object.create(Morris);

    MyMorris.Grid.prototype.gridDefaults["lineStyle"] = "";
 
    MyMorris.Line.prototype.drawLinePath = function(path, lineColor, lineIndex) {
      return this.raphael.path(path).attr('stroke', lineColor).attr('stroke-width', this.lineWidthForSeries(lineIndex)).attr('stroke-dasharray', this.options.lineStyle);
    };
}).call(this);

Morris.Area({
  element: 'chart',
  data: [
    { y: 'LUN', a: 1, b: 2 },
    { y: 'MAR', a: 2,  b: 3 },
    { y: 'MER', a: 4,  b: 2 },
    { y: 'JEU', a: 2,  b: 1 },
    { y: 'VEN', a: 2,  b: 2 },
    { y: 'SAM', a: 4,  b: 3 },
    { y: 'DIM', a: 1, b: 2 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2'],
  fillOpacity: 0.6,
  hideHover: 'auto',
  behaveLikeLine: true,
  resize: true,
  pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
  pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
  lineColors: ['gray', 'blue'],
  lineStyle: ".",
  parseTime: false,
  smooth: false,
  hoverCallback: function (index, options, content, row) {
    var currentDiv = "";
    var finalContent = $("<div/>");

    $(content).each(function () {
  currentDiv = $(this);
        $(finalContent).append(currentDiv);
    });
            
    var btnEdit = $("<img/>").attr("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2AxP.png").addClass("morrisEdit").css({"cursor":"pointer"}).attr("onclick", "editAction();");
    $(finalContent).append(btnEdit);
    return finalContent;    
  }
});

function editAction() {
  alert("Edit Clicked");
  // Do some actions
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Static solution:

```js
(function () {
    var $, MyMorris;

    MyMorris = window.MyMorris = {};
    $ = jQuery;

    MyMorris = Object.create(Morris);

    MyMorris.Grid.prototype.gridDefaults["lineStyle"] = "";

    MyMorris.Line.prototype.drawLinePath = function (path, lineColor, lineIndex) {
        return this.raphael.path(path).attr('stroke', lineColor).attr('stroke-width', this.lineWidthForSeries(lineIndex)).attr('stroke-dasharray', this.options.lineStyle);
    };
}).call(this);

var data = [
 { y: 'LUN', a: 1, b: 2 },
 { y: 'MAR', a: 2, b: 3 },
 { y: 'MER', a: 0, b: 2 },
 { y: 'JEU', a: 2, b: 1 },
 { y: 'VEN', a: 2, b: 2 },
 { y: 'SAM', a: 0, b: 0 },
 { y: 'DIM', a: 1, b: 2 }
];

Morris.Area({
    element: 'chart',
    data: data,
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
    labels: ['Label 1', 'Label 2'],
    fillOpacity: 0.6,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    behaveLikeLine: true,
    resize: true,
    pointFillColors: ['#ffffff'],
    pointStrokeColors: ['black'],
    lineColors: ['gray', 'blue'],
    lineStyle: ".",
    parseTime: false,
    smooth: false,
});

var indexNulls = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].a == 0 || data[i].b == 0) {
        indexNulls.push(i);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < indexNulls.length; i++) {
    var circleElement = $("#chart").find("circle")[indexNulls[i]];
    var divPosition = $(circleElement).attr("cx") - 20;
    $divEdit = $("<div/>").css({ "display": "inline-block", "position": "absolute", "left": divPosition + "px" });
    $btnEdit = $("<img/>").attr("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2AxP.png").addClass("morrisEdit").css({ "cursor": "pointer" }).attr("onclick", "editAction();");
    $divEdit.append($btnEdit);
    $("#edits").append($divEdit);
}

function editAction() {
    alert("Edit Clicked");
    // Do some actions
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="edits" style="width: 100%; margin-top: -150px; position: relative;">
```

Comment: Thank you So much, your answer help ...

However is it possible that the buttons still displayed  with Morris.js ?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure to have understood your question. You mean always display the edit button, not only on mouse over?

Comment: Yes .. Exactly ... Not only on mouse over :)

Comment: There's  no built-in option to do that with Morris so you have to find a trick. How you want your button(s) exactly, where and to do what?

Comment: Yes .... the buttons are displayed in the area with null value (in my picture = the area not blue where we found the buttons) .... the button permit to fill the data of these days (with null values) ...

Comment: I tried a trick as follow : display the buttons in the bottom of the chart (below the x axis) -- after that I put a negative padding to push the button up (in the chart) .... however when I do like that the buttons will be no more clickable (because of the svg)

Comment: Ok. I will try tomorrow. It's getting late for me.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much :)

Comment: I added a static solution: buttons always visible for data with 0 values.

Comment: This is so awesome and very helpful @krlzlx, thank you so much :)

Comment: Hello @krlzlx : I asked a new question, could you help me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618601/skipping-null-values-with-morris-js

Thank you