# Fill gaps in edge of a polygon

Tags: math, language-agnostic, draw, polygon

I'm using pygame to draw polygons but when the line is too thick, there are gaps in the edges of the polygon. I want these gaps to be filled.  The solution I found was to draw a filled polygon with 4 points in all the gaps as you can see on the image below. But I don't know how to find the 4 points of the polygon and that's my question. Also if you can find a better solution that would be great.

[image: What I need]

Note: The polygon isn't always regular, it's just made from many points. Also it's alright if your solution is not in python.

Comment: You want a miter joint. A round join is much easier and look good too. See the picture in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10943245/107090.

Comment: I might include both, but I'll start with miter

Answer (score 1):

If your polygon has no acute angles (where direction changes by more than 90°),
at each corner point, extend both lines by `(lineWidth/2)*tan(angle)`. The angle is the amount of direction change, not the inner angle between the segments.

If you do have acute angles, it gets more complicated. The line segments can no longer be drawn as rectangles and you must only extend the 'outer' edge of the polygon. The formula for that is the same.

Comment: I has to work with all kind of polygons so that wouldn't work as you said

Answer (score 0):

You can extend lines so that they can fill the gap. Although [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3rCt.png)
 is not good, it may be enough to visualize the idea.

Comment: I noticed @Frank Puffer suggested the same idea.